# Google Sheets Script question: Code error that I can't figure out

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-formula

So I have this code in my google sheets script editor right now. Pretty much what I'm trying to do is set a function that when a specific edit occurs in a designated column that it'll send out an email to the email address that's in an adjacent cell in that row that had the edit occur.

I keep getting this error though:
TypeError: sheet.getRange(...).getvalue is not a function (line 4, file "Code")

Here's the code I have so far:

```
function checkvalue(e) {
    var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    var sheet=ss.getSheetByName("Scheduling");
    var valueToCheck=sheet.getRange("A1").getvalue();
    var rangeEdit=e.range.getA1Notation();
    
    if(rangeEdit=="A1"){
    if(valuetocheck="NEEDS RESCHEDULED"){
  // Fetch the email address
var emailRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Scheduling").getRange("columnQ");
var emailAddress = emailRange.getValues();
// Send Alert Email.
var message = 'MYMESSAGE'; // Second column
var subject = 'MYSUBJECT';
MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message); 
}
}
}
```

,,,

Answer (score 1):

`var valueToCheck=sheet.getRange("A1").getvalue();` should be  `var valueToCheck=sheet.getRange("A1").getValue();`

also:

`var emailRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Scheduling").getRange("columnQ");` should be `var emailRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Scheduling").getRange(1,17,SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getLastRow(),1);

And possibly others